# Fetching only the last row of a mysql query with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select

Is it possible to fetch only the last row returned from a mysql query.  For example.  Let's say I have

`$result=mysql_query("SELECT * from mytable)`

It returns many rows.  the only way I know to get the data is to use a `while` loop like this

`while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  ...  }`

I know what you're thinking... Why not just do a query to `SELECT` only the last row?  But lets say that's out of my control. The query is already done and it's got lots of rows and I don't want to do another query.  Is the only way to get the last row, to go through the entire `while` loop and then look at the last data returned?  Or is there a way to maybe fetch the rows backwards and stop at the first one. Actually, if it makes it any easier, I don't really even need the entire last row.  I want to know what's in the last column of the last row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you use obsolete mysql api, you can use [`mysql_data_seek`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php#refsect1-function.mysql-data-seek-examples).

Link provides you an example, you can do something like:

```
mysql_data_seek($result, mysql_num_rows($result) - 1);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

More up-to-date `mysqli` also has [this feature](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.data-seek.php).

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

Alternatively PHP Answer:

```
$lastElement = array_values(array_slice($array, -1))[0];
```

If you run that on your query results you can just get the value this way.

Comment: the question was asking how to do it without a different query. I need a php answer

Comment: Why not just build this into your original query? You don't need to run 2 queries.

Comment: @CheeseFlavored Added a php answer for you as well

Comment: I am looking for a php answer, I tried `$lastElement = array_values(array_slice(mysql_fetch_array($result), -1))[0];`  but it didn't give me the last element

Comment: Then your select query is sorting it wrong and you will have to modify it. Otherwise there's no easy answer.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**

You can have a variable outside of the loop that saves the last row like so:

```
$lastRow = null;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{  
    $lastRow = $row;
}

$value = lastRow['ColumnName'];
```

You can now use lastRow anywhere outside of the query.

**SQL**

You can order by descending to flip the table.

```
SELECT ColumnName FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

LIMIT 1 would only return 1 row.

Comment: the question was asking how to do it without a different query. I need a php answer based on the query that was already done.

Comment: @CheeseFlavored I have updated my answer